# How can I get the list of my active sessions from Facebook?

Tags: facebook

Is there a an API call with which I can request all active sessions for a specific account?

For example, if I visit

```
https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=security&section=sessions&view
```

I can see a list of all the places I'm logged in from, e.g. my phone, my work PC and anywhere else that is currently logged into my account.

How can I get this data?

Comment: i dont think that would be wise for fb to expose that.

Comment: Why not? (assuming I've authenticated)